# Program to output Low and High pass filter impulse response coefficients for signal processing

Tags: c++, vectors

My issue that I was trying to solve was constructing a vector where the values were mirrored around the central element. The problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876916/construct-mirror-vector-around-the-centre-element-in-c

I solved the issue using the method in the accepted answer and am sharing my working code to hear any review suggestions or edit to make my code more efficient.

My code solution:

**filters.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ErrorCode.h"
#include "variables.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

/*
 *  Functions for calculating the coefficients of the selected filter.
 *  Options: Low Pass, High Pass, Band Pass, Band Reject.
 *
 *  (To do: put functions in separate file, use of headers and classes - constructors?)
 *
 */

vector <double> lowPass (vector<double> hL, double fcL, int M, int N, const double PI)
{
    std::vector<int> mArr;
    mArr.resize(N);
    int count;
    for(count = 0; count < N; count++)
        mArr[count] = count - M;
    int n;
    for(n = 0; n < M; n++)
    {
        hL[n] = (sin((fcL*mArr[n])-M))/((mArr[n]-M)*PI);
    }
    hL[M] = fcL/PI;

    for(n = 0; n < M; n++)
    {
        hL[N-n-1] = hL[n];
    }

    return hL;
}

vector <double> highPass (vector<double> hH, double fcH, int M, int N, const double PI)
{
    std::vector<int> mArr;
    mArr.resize(N);
    int count;
    for(count = 0; count < N; count++)
        mArr[count] = count - M;
    int n;
    for(n = 0; n < M; n++)
    {
        hH[n] = -((sin((fcH*mArr[n])-M))/(mArr[n]-(M*PI)));
    }
    hH[M] = 1+(fcH/PI);

    for(n = 0; n < M; n++)
    {
        hH[N-n-1] = hH[n];
    }

    return hH;
}

vector<double> bandPass (vector<double> bp, vector<double> hL, vector<double> hH, double fcL, double fcH, int M, const double PI)
{
    for(int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        bp[n] = -(hH[n]) - hL[n];
        bp[M] = (fcH/PI) - (fcL/PI);
    }

    return bp;
}

vector<double> bandReject (vector<double> br, vector<double> hL, vector<double> hH, double fcL, double fcH, int M, const double PI)
{
    for(int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        br[n] = hL[n] - (-(hH[n]));
        br[M] = 1 + (fcL/PI) - (fcH/PI);
    }

    return br;
}

/*
 *  Functions for calculating the coefficients of the selected window filter.
 *  Options: Rectangular, Hanning, Hamming, Blackman Harris
 *
 *  (To do: put functions in separate file, use of headers and classes - constructors?)
 *
 */

vector<double> hanning(vector<double> hann, int M, int N, const double PI)
{
    std::vector<int> mArr;
    mArr.resize(N);
    int count;
    for(count = 0; count < N; count++)
        mArr[count] = count - M;

    for(int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        hann[n] = 0.5+(0.5*(cos((mArr[n]*PI)/M)));
    }
    return hann;
}

vector<double> hamming(vector<double> hamm, int N, const double PI)
{
    for(int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        hamm[n] = 0.54 - (0.46*(cos(n*2*PI/N)));
    }
    return hamm;
}

vector<double> blackman (vector<double> bmhr, int N, const double PI)
{
    for(int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        bmhr[n] = 0.42 - (0.5*(cos(2*PI*n/N))) + (0.08*cos(4*PI*n/N));
    }

    return bmhr;
}

/*
 *  Functions to calculate cut-off frequency for low and high
 */

double calcFcL (double f_cL, double f_s)
{
    double fcL = f_cL/f_s;
    return fcL;
}

double calcFcH (double f_cH, double f_s)
{
    double fcH = f_cH/f_s;
    return fcH;
}

/*
 * Check if cut off frequencies are lower than the sampling frequency
 * Check if filter length is odd
 */

ErrorCode checkFreq(double, double, double);
ErrorCode checkN(int);
ErrorCode checkNs(int);
ErrorCode checkF1(double);
ErrorCode checkF2(double);
ErrorCode checkA1(double);
ErrorCode checkA2(double);


/*
 *  User input for selecting filter type
 *  Options: Low Pass, High Pass, Band Pass, Band Reject
 *  Passes filter output of function by value
 *  Output coefficients to a csv file
 */

vector<double> filterType(vector<double> filter, double fcL, double fcH, int M, int N, const double PI)
{
    int choice;
    cout <<"Please select filter type:  \n";

    cout << "1: Low Pass\n"
            "2: High Pass\n"
            "3: Band Pass\n"
            "4: Band Reject\n";

    cout << "Enter your selection (1, 2, 3 or 4): ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice)
    {
            case 1:
                {
                vector<double> hL;
                hL.resize(N);
                hL = lowPass(hL, fcL, M, N, PI);
                ofstream lpfile ("lowpass.csv");
                if (lpfile.is_open())
                {
                    for(int count = 0; count < N; count++){
                        lpfile << hL[count] << "," ;
                    }
                    lpfile.close();
                }
                else cout << "Unable to open file";
                filter = hL;
                break;
                }


            case 2:
                {
                vector<double> hH;
                hH.resize(N);
                hH = highPass(hH, fcH, M, N, PI);
                ofstream hpfile ("highpass.csv");
                if (hpfile.is_open())
                {
                for(int count = 0; count < N; count++){
                    hpfile << hH[count] << "," ;
                    }
                hpfile.close();
                }
                else cout << "Unable to open file";
                filter = hH;
                break;
                }


            case 3:
                {
                vector<double> hL;
                hL.resize(N);
                vector<double> hH;
                hH.resize(N);
                vector<double> bp;
                bp.resize(N);
                hL = lowPass(hL, fcL, M, N, PI);
                hH = highPass(hH, fcH, M, N, PI);

                bp = bandPass(bp, hL, hH, fcL, fcH, M, PI);
                ofstream bpfile ("bandpass.csv");
                if (bpfile.is_open())
                {
                for(int count = 0; count < N; count++){
                    bpfile << bp[count] << "," ;
                    }
                bpfile.close();
                }
                else cout << "Unable to open file";
                filter  = bp;
                break;
                }


            case 4:
                {
                vector<double> hL;
                hL.resize(N);
                vector<double> hH;
                hH.resize(N);
                vector<double> br;
                br.resize(N);
                hL = lowPass(hL, fcL, M, N, PI);
                hH = highPass(hH, fcH, M, N, PI);
                br = bandReject(br, hL, hH, fcL, fcH, M, PI);
                ofstream brfile ("bandreject.csv");
                if (brfile.is_open())
                {
                for(int count = 0; count < N; count++){
                    brfile << br[count] << "," ;
                    }
                brfile.close();
                }
                else cout << "Unable to open file";
                filter = br;
                break;
                }


            default:
                break;


    }
    return filter;
}

/*
 *  User input for selecting window type
 *  Options: Rectangular, Hanning, Hamming, Blackman Harris
 *  Passes window output of function by value
 *  Output coefficients to a csv file
 */

vector<double> windowType(vector<double> window, int M, int N, const double PI)
{
    int choice;
    cout <<"Please select Window type:  \n";

    cout << "1: Rectangular\n"
            "2: Hanning\n"
            "3: Hamming\n"
            "4: Blackman Harris\n";

    cout << "Enter your selection (1, 2, 3 or 4): ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice)
    {
            case 1:
                {
                    vector<double> rect;
                    rect.assign (N, 1);
                    ofstream rectfile ("rectangular.csv");
                    if (rectfile.is_open())
                    {
                        for(int count = 0; count < N; count++){
                            rectfile << rect[count] << "," ;
                            }
                        rectfile.close();
                    }
                    else cout << "Unable to open file";
                    window = rect;
                    break;
                }

            case 2:
                {
                    vector<double> hann = {};
                    hann.resize(N);
                    hann = hanning(hann, M, N, PI);
                    ofstream hannfile ("hanning.csv");
                    if (hannfile.is_open())
                    {
                        for(int count = 0; count < N; count++){
                            hannfile << hann[count] << "," ;
                            }
                        hannfile.close();
                    }
                    else cout << "Unable to open file";
                    window = hann;
                    break;
                }

            case 3:
                {
                    vector<double> hamm = {};
                    hamm.resize(N);
                    hamm = hamming(hamm, N, PI);
                    ofstream hammfile ("hamming.csv");
                    if (hammfile.is_open())
                    {
                        for(int count = 0; count < N; count++){
                            hammfile << hamm[count] << "," ;
                            }
                        hammfile.close();
                    }
                    else cout << "Unable to open file";
                    window = hamm;
                    break;
                }

            case 4:
                {
                    vector<double> bmhr = {};
                    bmhr.resize(N);
                    bmhr = blackman(bmhr, N, PI);
                    ofstream bmhrfile ("blackman.csv");
                    if (bmhrfile.is_open())
                    {
                        for(int count = 0; count < N; count++){
                            bmhrfile << bmhr[count] << "," ;
                            }
                        bmhrfile.close();
                    }
                    else cout << "Unable to open file";
                    window = bmhr;
                    break;
                }

    }
    return window;
}

/*
 *  Combine window filter with filter to generate FIR coefficients
 */

vector<double> finiteIR(vector<double> fir, vector<double> filter, vector<double> window, int N)
{
    for(int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        fir[n] = filter[n]*window[n];
    }
    ofstream firfile ("FIR.csv");
    if (firfile.is_open())
    {
        for(int count = 0; count < N; count++){
            firfile << fir[count] << "," ;
        }
        firfile.close();
    }
        else cout << "Unable to open file";
    return fir;
}

vector<complex<double> > genSignal(vector<complex<double> > signal, double f_s, int N_s, double f1, double f2, double a1, double a2, const double PI)
{
    complex<double> i = -1;
    i = sqrt(i);
    double tP = 1/f_s;
    vector<double> t;
    t.resize(N_s);
    for(int n = 0; n < N_s - 1; n++)
    {
        t[n] = n*tP;
    }
    vector<complex<double> > x = {};
    double x1Real;
    double x1Imag;
    double x2Real;
    double x2Imag;
    for (int n = 0; n < N_s; n++)
    {
      x1Real = real(a1*exp(i*(2*PI*f1*t[n])));
      x1Imag = imag(a1*exp(i*(2*PI*f1*t[n])));
      x2Real = real(a2*exp(i*(2*PI*f2*t[n])));
      x2Imag = imag(a2*exp(i*(2*PI*f2*t[n])));
      double xreal = x1Real + x2Real;
      double ximag = x1Imag + x2Imag;
      complex<double> iNum(xreal, ximag);
      x.push_back(iNum);
    }

    ofstream sigfile ("signal.csv");
    if (sigfile.is_open())
    {
        for(int count = 0; count < N_s; count++)
        {
            sigfile << real(x[count]) << "," ;
            sigfile << imag(x[count]) << ",\n" ;
        }
        sigfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    signal = x;

    return signal;

}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    double f_cL;
    double f_cH;
    cout << "Enter Low Cut-Off frequency (Hz) [Set to 0 for the highpass filter] : ";
    cin >> f_cL;
    cout << "Enter High Cut-Off frequency (Hz) [Set to 0 for the lowpass filter] : ";
    cin >> f_cH;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    cout << "Enter sampling frequency (Hz): ";
    cin >> f_s;
    if (checkFreq(f_s, f_cL, f_cH) == ErrorCode::FAIL)
    {
        std::cout << "You entered a frequency less than cut-off!\n";
        cout << "Fail";
        return 0;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    cout << "Enter Order of the filter (filter length): ";
    cin >> N;
    if (checkN(N) == ErrorCode::FAIL)
    {
        cout << "You entered an invalid number!\n";
        cout << "Fail";
        return 0;
    }

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    double fcL;
    double fcH;
    fcL = calcFcL(f_cL, f_s);
    cout << "FcL is : " << fcL << endl;
    fcH = calcFcH(f_cH, f_s);
    cout << "FcH is: " << fcH << endl;

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    int M = (N-1)/2;
    vector<double> filter;
    filter.resize(N);
    filter = filterType(filter, fcL, fcH, M, N, PI);

    vector<double> window;
    window.resize(N);
    window = windowType(window, M, N, PI);

    vector<double> fir;
    fir.resize(N);
    fir = finiteIR(fir, filter, window, N);

    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    cout << "\n\n" << "Generate Signal...\n";
    cout << "Enter signal sample length: ";
    cin >> N_s;
    if (checkNs(N_s) == ErrorCode::FAIL)
    {
        cout << "You entered an invalid number!\n";
        cout << "Fail";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Enter frequency 1 (Hz): ";
    cin >> f1;
    if (checkF1(f1) == ErrorCode::FAIL)
    {
        cout << "You entered an invalid frequency!\n";
        cout << "Fail";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Enter frequency 2 (Hz): ";
    cin >> f2;
    if (checkF2(f2) == ErrorCode::FAIL)
    {
        cout << "You entered an invalid frequency!\n";
        cout << "Fail";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Enter Amplitude 1: ";
    cin >> a1;
    if (checkA1(a1) == ErrorCode::FAIL)
    {
        cout << "You entered an invalid frequency!\n";
        cout << "Fail";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Enter Amplitude 2 (Hz): ";
    cin >> a2;
    if (checkA2(a2) == ErrorCode::FAIL)
    {
        cout << "You entered an invalid frequency!\n";
        cout << "Fail";
        return 0;
    }


    vector<complex<double> > signal;
    signal = genSignal(signal, f_s, N_s, f1, f2, a1, a2, PI);

    return 0;
}
```

**error.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ErrorCode.h"

ErrorCode checkFreq(double value, double value2, double value3)
{
    // if value is less than cut-off
    if (value < value2 || value < value3)
       // early return an error code
        return ErrorCode::FAIL;

    // Success
    return ErrorCode::SUCCESS;
}

ErrorCode checkN(int value)
{
    // if value is even
    if(value % 2 == 0 || value < 0)
      // early return an error code
        return ErrorCode::FAIL;

    // Success
    return ErrorCode::SUCCESS;
}

ErrorCode checkNs(int value)
{
    // if value is negative
    if(value < 0)
      // early return an error code
        return ErrorCode::FAIL;

    // Success
    return ErrorCode::SUCCESS;
}

ErrorCode checkF1(double value)
{
    // if value is negative
    if(value < 0)
      // early return an error code
        return ErrorCode::FAIL;

    // Success
    return ErrorCode::SUCCESS;
}

ErrorCode checkF2(double value)
{
    // if value is negative
    if(value < 0)
      // early return an error code
        return ErrorCode::FAIL;

    // Success
    return ErrorCode::SUCCESS;
}

ErrorCode checkA1(double value)
{
    // if value is negative
    if(value < 0)
      // early return an error code
        return ErrorCode::FAIL;

    // Success
    return ErrorCode::SUCCESS;
}

ErrorCode checkA2(double value)
{
    // if value is negative
    if(value < 0)
      // early return an error code
        return ErrorCode::FAIL;

    // Success
    return ErrorCode::SUCCESS;
}
```

**ErrorCode.h**

```
#ifndef ERRORCODE_H_INCLUDED
#define ERRORCODE_H_INCLUDED

enum class ErrorCode
{
    SUCCESS = 0,
    FAIL = -1
};

#endif // ERRORCODE_H_INCLUDED
```

**variables.h**

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H_INCLUDED
#define VARIABLES_H_INCLUDED


double f_c = 0.0, f_s = 0.0, fc = 0.0, w_c = 0.0;
double N_s = 0.0, f1 = 0.0, f2 = 0.0, a1 = 0.0, a2 = 0.0;
int N = 0;
const double PI  = 3.141592653589793238463;

#endif // VARIABLES_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Welcome to code review, where we review working code to provide suggestions on how to improve the code, unfortunately this code doesn't seem to be in a function or a class, which makes the code incomplete. Could you please supply at least the entire function, and possibly the class or entire program?

Comment: I have edited to include my full program. Apologies there are little comments in the code at the moment, I'm working on that and will edit in due course. This is a program to produce impulse response coefficients for using in Low and High Pass filters for signal processing.

Comment: This won't compile as presented. lowPass has a different signature from its use in filter type, checkFreq and checkN are missing from ErrorCode.h and filterType in main.c doesn't make sense

Comment: Did you test this? It looks like `lowPass` takes no arguments while you do pass those to it.

Comment: Please [edit] the actual working code into the post; code with compile errors cannot be reviewed.

Comment: edits have now been made and the code is now updated, including comments.